# How to lock in radio stations in Grand Theft Auto IV?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-iv

Is there a way to lock a radio station to always be a specific one, or to at least eliminate radio stations I don't particularly care for?  Some of the stations *really* annoy me, and I am tired of having to press on the d-pad to find one that doesn't make my teeth grit.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's a menu screen that lists all the radio stations, and you can toggle them on or off.  If you turn them all off, the radio never comes on.  If you turn all but one off, that one will always play in whatever vehicle you're in.  It's been a while, though.

Comment: The stupid radio stations add to the atmosphere when you're jacking people's cars.

Comment: @agent86.  I remember that function in a game as well, but that is unfortunately NOT this game.

Comment: @Nick T.  It does add to the atmosphere, but how many people in Liberty City actually listen to (bad) reggae compared to the number that play it in their cars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there aren't any settings related to radio stations as you described above. Only thing I recall is the ability to just turn the radio station down or up (start > audio).

Comment: I agree.  Can't seem to change defaults regardless.  Only luck I had was using the same car over and over.  The radio doesn't change then.